# Which is the best way to read values from database and display?

Tags: mysql, database, javafx, javafx-2

Am trying to read some values from a table in MySQL database.  The table has only one column and 4 rows. My code is below. I know how to read all the values. But when you look at the code you can understand that am only able to display one of the value from the database, that is the last value of the table (the value in the last row).

What I need is to display all the values in the table. Am not an experienced programmer. So tell me how can I read and display all the values in the table. There is one more condition - I need different button names for each value in the table, so that I can add setOnAction() function to each button.

If there is a better idea than using buttons, tell me that too. But it shouldn't be complex.

```
private VBox userSelection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    VBox vb1 = new VBox();
    vb1.setPadding(new Insets(40, 150, 20, 150));
    vb1.setSpacing(20);

    Button b = null;

    Text scenetitle2 = new Text("Choose Your Account");
    scenetitle2.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?"
                        + "user=root&password=virus");
    statement = connect.createStatement();

    rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from user");

    while (rs.next()) {

        String username = rs.getString("staffname");

        b = new Button(username);
        b.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 17));
        b.setStyle(" -fx-base: #333333;");
        b.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        b.setPrefSize(150,30);

    }

    vb1.getChildren().addAll(scenetitle2,b);        
    return vb1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if I follow what the problem is but...

I see that in your While loop, you overwrite your Button b object without adding it to your VBox. So only the last Button object will be added. Basicly you have to do something like this:

```
vb1.getChildren().add(scenetitle2);  
while (rs.next()) {

    String username = rs.getString("staffname");

    b = new Button(username);
    b.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 17));
    b.setStyle(" -fx-base: #333333;");
    b.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
    b.setPrefSize(150,30);

    b.setOnAction(...) //add handler to button

    vb1.getChildren().add(b); //add button object to your vbox inside the loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still 1 more problem is there. All buttons are having the same name. So how can I make setOnAction() function workable for each button.

Comment: The same way, add the setOnAction() in the While loop before you add the button to your VBox, see edited code

Comment: Will it work ? I mean, will it cause some problems or contradictions if button names are same.

Comment: What if I need to add setOnAction() later ?

Comment: Define 'later'? And what do you mean with 'button names are the same'? Your button object 'b' is always a new one as you go through the While loop because of this line `b = new Button(username);`

Comment: Later means outside the while loop. Suppose I called b.setOnAction() outside the while loop. Since multiple values have read from the database, button to which corresponding value will get invoked ?